What did Bradley mean that it "may be true" that all trespassers will be prosecuted?
What exactly did F. H. Bradley mean when he wrote in his 1883 Principles of Logic that the statement that all trespassers will be prosecuted "may be true"?
Did he mean that the statement is at least in some cases definitely true?
Or did he mean rather that the statement is in the best of cases only possibly true?
Thank you for any scholarly references.

It is a promise, a law, and thus we need counterfactual conditional to analyze it. If we use classical truth-functional logic, that consider it as the expression of a fact, we get that a single unnoticed (by the policeman) trespasser will be a counterexample falsifyung the general statement.

"Will be" is a mandatory conditional, so it means without exception. "May be" means it is allowed / possible but with no certainty of occurrence. So he basically said, "yes or no" which means nothing.

Do you mean this passage:""All  persons  found trespassing on this  ground will be prosecuted,"  is  too often a prophecy, as well as a promise. But it
is not meant to foretell, and, though no one trespasses,  the statement may be true"? He refers to what is now called "vacuous truth" in a conditional, if no one trespasses the conditional premised on it is true. He adds ""all  triangles  have  their  angles equal to two right angles"  would hardly be false if there were no triangles" right after.

@ScottRowe "which means nothing" To you. Russell agreed with Bradley on this specific point.

@MauroALLEGRANZA "a single unnoticed (by the policeman) trespasser will be a counterexample" Any reference for that?

It is simply a comment to Bradley, page 49: "The universal judgment is thus always hypothetical. It says “Given one thing you will then have another,” and it says no more. No truth can state fact." If we read as expressing a fact, the universal hypothetical "For every x (if x is a trespasser, then x is prosecuted)" will be falsified by a single case of a trespasser that will not be prosecuted, because the trespassing has not been noticed by e.g. a policeman. The negation of the universal is "there is an x that (x is a trespasser and x is not prosecuted)".
